# The equation $2x=a$ has no solution in an infinite additive cyclic group generated by $a$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups, infinite-groups

> Q: If $G$ is an infinite additive cyclic group with the generator element $a$, prove that the equation $2x=a$ has no solution in $G$, $x \in G $.

Answer:

Since $G$ is an infinite cyclic group then $|a|= \infty$ (where $|a|$ denotes the order of $a$)

Since $x \in G $ there for $x=ia$

$$2x=a  \Rightarrow 2ia=a$$

$$a(2i-1)=0$$

i'm stuck here so i don't know how to prove that this is unsolvable

Comment: You're mixing additive notation ($2x = x+x$) with multiplicative notation ($x = a^i = a \times a \times \cdots \times a$)

Comment: Edited, I'm so sorry it's due to lack of sleep i guess

Comment: Please don't change the question once it has been answered.

Comment: Having said that, I have updated my answer.

Comment: If you have another question,  post it. Don't edit an already answered one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have shown that $\lvert a\rvert$ divides the absolute value of $2i-1$. But the order of $a$ is infinite.

---

Alternatively, $G\cong\Bbb Z$ is free of rank one and so has no torsion (but this jumps the gun a bit).

Answer (score 2):

$(2i-1)a=0$ implies the order of $a$ is finite. That's a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

Using additive notation: if $a$ generates the group $G$ and $2x = a$ for some $x \in G$, then, because $a$ generates $G$, $x = ma$ for some $m \in \Bbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}$, giving us that $2ma = a$. So $G$ cannot be infinite, since we must have $(2m-1)a = 0$.